# How to ban thousands of IP addresses on 2008 Server

Tags: firewall, blocking, netsh

I'm trying to block the Tor Project network from my webserver as many spam/malicous scripts are using it to flood my API.

I've tried almost every method possible it seems there is NO WAY to append IP's to an existing rule using "netsh advfirewall firewall" and when I try to add all the IP's from a single command line I hit the command prompt character length limit and can only add about 100 or so IP's of the 6,000.

when using netsh -f "script file" also seems to have the same limitations.

so what is the best method for blocking these IP's?:
https://www.dan.me.uk/torlist/

Thanks.

Comment: What's the OS version?

Comment: Windows Server 2008 R2 Standard SP1 with IIS7

Comment: Have you tried combining it with powershell?

Comment: Also, have you considered using Application Control Policies (a.k.a AppLocker)? You can block all executables quite easily, and allow only those you know. Only the most advanced malware can bypass that.